# BJT with fast turn off characteristics

Tags: bjt

I need a bjt that can be used for serial transmition in the range of 50MHz and therefore needs a fast turn off characteristics. I'm looking for parameters as `storage time` and `fall time` but these are seldom mentioned in the datasheets. Are there other parameters I can take as reference for a fast turn off behavior? I assume a small collector base capacitance is also desirable. Would something like the MMBT5179 be capable of driving 50MHz signal when some additional turn off boosts (e.g. saturation limiter) are in place?

The one that is currently used is an MMBT2222 in an SOT-23 package, so the new one would need to be in the same package.
Looking at the signal at the transistor base, the fall time looks okay, at least much faster than the one on the collector.

[image]

**update:**
Here is a measurement of the transistors base voltage. I'd say the switch off looks okay and seems to be fast enough.
[image]

And that's the voltage on the collector (not the same bit-pattern though). The problem in my opinion is that the third turn off pulse (1bit width) doesn't rise fast enough, therefore not reaching 5V and as a concequence my laser diode doesn't turn of properly. What is the cause of the capacitive effect we see starting at 3.26V? C305 and C307 are removed but the signal shape didn't change significantly.
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116770/discussion-on-question-by-po-pe-bjt-with-fast-turn-off-characteristics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The transistor turns on and off fine (red arrows) but as you noticed there's something that looks like a RC discharge curve (highlighted in green).

This is due to the LED*'s internal capacitance. When the transistor is on, the LED's capacitance is charged to Vf. When the transistor turns off, the LED capacitance will discharge, rather slowly, through the LED itself which creates exactly the type of curve shown on this scope shot. This means the light output will have the same decay instead of turning off quickly.

(* I call it a LED, maybe it's a laser diode, but you get the idea)

The way to solve this is to discharge the LED capacitance when turning it off. That's why I suggested driving it from a 74ACT logic gate, which has push-pull output and 3.3V compatible input levels. That's also what the recommended schematic in the datasheet does.

However you can't do that since you don't want to change the PCB and you probably don't have enough room for a SOIC14 chip, and I couldn't find any 74ACT in single gate SOT-23.

You could simply stick a resistor in parallel with the LED to speed up the internal capacitance discharge when it turns off. Start with doing that and see if it fixes your RC decay. If it does then my hunch is correct and the culprit is the capacitance.

If this is the case then you'll need a push pull driver, either implemented with two BJTs or logic gates.

Comment: I've put a 100R resistor in parallel with the HFBR and the signal shape improved a lot. I agree that something with a sinking capability might be a considerble replacement for the bjt in a future redesign.

Comment: Great! Well it'll waste a bit of current with the 100R resistor but at least it works.

Comment: @po.pe I would recommend using one of [these](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74LVC1G17DBVR/389051), personally. Just a cheap logic buffer in a sot-23-5 package, can both source and sink current.

Comment: @Hearth that is a non-inverting buffer. OP may be better off with an inverting buffer to preserve existing polarity. Just a note for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ready circuit board and only components can be changed to pin for pin equivalent models the case can be tricky.

I guess your signal output in the right edge of the drawing cannot sink enough current. The needed turn-off current pulse can be more than the LED current in the ON-state. Try to simulate with ideal voltage pulse source and see if the current is within the capabilities of your FPGA output.

If you can change the circuit try to use emitter follower. It doesn't get saturated. An example:

[image]

[image]

R3 (=1Ohm) is there to have an easy way both to show the input current (=i(R3)) and to test what a series resistance causes. The input current is well below 1mA.

The diode is a randomly selected piece.

If one tests this with an oscilloscope (at the emitter) the result can look bad because nothing discharges the diode capacitance. But the current (=i(D1)) follows well the input voltage (=v(5)).

ADD: You wrote the base voltage looks OK, it falls fast. Then the storage time isn't your problem. But I just noticed your circuit has capacitors C305A and C307A. They in series with the diode capacitance pull your transistor on its knees. Remove them.

ADD2 further checks show that my emitter follower buffer is useless as opto-fiber LED driver. It lets diode minority carriers live as long as they want and make light well beyond the current has stopped. Having the right diode current pulse form means nothing, the diode voltage must be shorted to stop the light generation fast. For that reason recommended application notes have totem pole output for transmitting diodes. It can as well pull the needed current as short the stored voltage at the end of the pulse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The limited sinking capability of the FPGA pin might well be a problem but wouldn't I see this already when measuring the base voltage? I can take a scope picture, maybe that helps. As I cannot change the circuit, emitter follower is not an option. But what about NMOS FET, would that be able to switch off faster?

Comment: Could you quickly explain the bad impact of C305 and C307? My understanding was that they would help to "push" the cathode of the laser diode towards 5V when the transistor starts blocking and therefore help to have a sharper turn off behavior... so I guess I was wrong with my assumption.

Comment: Nothing lifts the bottom end of C305,C307 . Forget the 1kOhm resistor, its time constant is far too long. Remove the capacitors and tell the result. I guess many of us are interested in.

Comment: I'll remove them tomorrow morning and give an update

Comment: @po.pe after removing the capacitors the diode current probably follows well the drive pulses. The high capacitance only keeps the cathode of the diode a long time well below +Vcc. The same happens in my alternative buffer; the voltage at the emitter looks bad but diode current is OK. For good looking Vce plots you need something which pulls the cathode up fast enough but that's not needed for diode current.  BUT: The voltage caused by  diode capacitance is  minority carriers which vanish gradually due the recombination. Unfortunately it makes light, right current means nothing, voltage counts

Answer (score 1):

I've used the 2N5179 at moderate currents (10mA) for Phase Locked Loops, in CURRENT STEERING Mode, for rather low pulse widths from MECL comparators and MECL logic.

Again, at moderate currents.

And also used the 2N5179 (from my junk box, a Motorola part) as the bottom transistor in a cascade amplifier for 45.75MHz carrier of TV downconverter of channel 2/3/4.
The recovered video was indistinguishable from the original/modulating video.

Again at moderate currents (5mA, for downconverter).

Notice neither of these were in saturating circuits.

The American_made Moto parts (now the ONNN Semi plant) behaved well at low Vce.

The available_in_volume (Korean_made) parts had unacceptable gain at low Vce.

So be careful with sourcing. And datecodes.